# Decomposition of vector field into solenoidal and irrotational parts.

Tags: proof-writing, vector-analysis

Can a vector field $\mathbf{A}: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ always be expressed as the sum of a solenoidal (divergenceless) part $\mathbf{A}_S$, where $\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}_S = 0$, and an irrotational part $\mathbf{A}_R$, where $\nabla\times\mathbf{A}_R = 0$?

$$
“\,\forall{\mathbf{A}}\;
\exists{\mathbf{A}_S}\;
\exists{\mathbf{A}_R} :
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}_S + \mathbf{A}_R \;\wedge\;
\nabla \cdot \mathbf{A}_S = 0 \;\wedge\;
\nabla \times \mathbf{A}_R = 0
\,”\,?
$$

Since irrotational vector fields are gradients of some scalar field ($\mathbf{A}_R = \nabla R$), this is equivalent to asking:

$$
“\,
\forall\mathbf{A}\;
\exists\mathbf{A}_S\;
\exists R \in \left(\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow\mathbb{R}\right) :
\mathbf{A} = \mathbf{A}_S + \nabla R
\;\wedge\;
\nabla\cdot\mathbf{A}_S = 0
\,”\,?
$$

What’s a proof of the result? If true, are $\mathbf{A}_R$ and $\mathbf{A}_S$ unique?
If it’s not always true, then what kind of fields can/cannot be decomposed in this way?

---

If true, this would be a *very* nice result: any vector field could then be thought of in terms of its unique solenoidal and irrotational components.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is called **Helmholtz decomposition**, a.k.a., the *fundamental theorem of vector calculus*. Helmholtz’s theorem states that any vector field $\mathbf{F}$ on $\mathbb{R}^3$ can be written as
$$
\mathbf{F} =
\underbrace{-\nabla\Phi}_\text{irrotational} +
\underbrace{\nabla\times\mathbf{A}}_\text{solenoidal}
$$
provided 1) that $\mathbf{F}$ is twice continuously differentiable and 2) that $\mathbf{F}$ vanishes faster than $1/r$ as $r \rightarrow \infty$.
If $\mathbf{F}$ is on a bounded domain $V \subset \mathbb{R}^3$, then the condition 2) that $\mathbf{F}$ vanishes can be relaxed.

Helmholtz’s theorem even gives $\Phi$ and $\mathbf{A}$ in terms of $\mathbf{F}$. More details can be found here:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition